# Select2 on change removed id value

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2

On `select2` version 3 in event I get `e.removed.id` as value of previous `select2` value but not in version 4.

So this way I am not able to get the previous `select2` value which was changed. I can save it in variable but getting from event was easier.

Can anyone confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `removed` was replaced by `select2:unselect` event in fourth version of `select2` you could notice that in [version 4.0.0-BETA.2 BREAKING CHANGES](https://gemnasium.com/bower/select2/versions/4.0.0-beta.2).

> - All extra properties of **`change`** have been removed :
>
>   - **val** - Use **`$element.val()`** instead
>   - **removed** - Use the **`select2:unselect`** event instead
>   - **added** - Use the **`select2-selected`** event instead

Hope this helps.